# data from form in php on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Is is possible to send an array from javascript to php in the same page, before you submit?

I have a index.php with a form and when you change the value of an input use that and send it to php. then in php use it to make an http request and get back the newly calculated price. and use that price to display in the footer. buts it needs to be on the same page.

http://enjoytesting.nl/test/

so here you can see the input fields and if you change for example the duration i want to change the rental price in the footer.

EDIT: so I think my change function works and I think my ajax to but in my php I get the error Undefined index: date and Undefined index: quantity. is that because my php runs before my ajax sends it?

```
$('#beginTijd').change(function(){
    begin =( $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') ); 
    console.log(begin);      
});
$('#aantalSloepen').change(function(){
    aantal =( $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') ); 
    console.log(aantal);

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {date:begin, quantity: aantal},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(begin , aantal);
    }
});
});
```

php

```
$value1= $_POST['date'];  
$value2= $_POST['quantity'];     

echo $value1; 
echo $value2;
```

full code

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, 
maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>reserveren</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="BeschikbaarheidReserveren">
    <hr id="hrOne"><hr id="hrTwo"><hr class="hrActive" id="hrThree"><br>
    <h3>Beschikbaarheid &#38; Reserveren</h3>
    <div id="tableHeader">
      <img src="images/GJ_arrow-left.png" alt="left arrow">
      <img src="images/GJ_arrow-right.png" alt="right arrow">
      <h2 id="vestiging">Utrecht</h2>
    </div>
    <img id="gif" src="http://moziru.com/images/pointer-clipart-animated-gif-7.gif" alt="">
    <div class="container">
 <div class="fixed-th-table-wrapper">
<!-- fixed-th-table -->
<table>
<tr>
     <th class="TableGreenJoyGreen"></th>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">9u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">10u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">11u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">12u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">13u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">14u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">15u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">16u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">17u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">18u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">19u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">20u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">21u</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <th>Ma, 26/02/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
     <th>Di, 27/02/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
     <th>Wo, 28/02/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
     <th>Do, 01/03/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
     <th>Vr, 02/03/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
     <th>Za, 03/03/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
     <th>Zo, 04/03/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

 <div class="scrolled-td-table-wrapper"> 
<!-- scrolled-td-table
 - same as fixed-th-table -->
<table>
<tr>
     <th class="TableGreenJoyGreen"></th>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen"> 9u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">10u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">11u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">12u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">13u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">14u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">15u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">16u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">17u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">18u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">19u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">20u</td>
     <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">21u</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <th>Ma, 26/02/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
     <th>Di, 27/02/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
     <th>Wo, 28/02/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
     <th>Do, 29/02/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <th>Vr, 01/03/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <th>Za, 02/03/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <th>Zo, 03/03/2018</th>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="wrap">
<div id="fp1"><div class="circleBase type1"></div><p>Beschikbaar</p></div>
<div id="fp2"><div class="circleBase type2"></div><p>Enkelen beschikbaar</p>
</div>
<div id="fp3"><div class="circleBase type3"></div><p>Uitverkocht</p></div>
<div id="fp4"><div class="circleBase type4"></div><p>Niet beschikbaar</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<form action="betalen.php" method="post" id="form1">
<label for="date">Datum*</label>
<span>
<input name="datum" type="date" id="datum" required>
</span>
<br>

<label for="beginTijd">BeginTijd*</label>
<span>
<select name="beginTijd" id="beginTijd" required>
<option value="09:00">9u</option>
<option value="10:00">10u</option>
<option value="11:00">11u</option>
<option value="12:00">12u</option>
<option value="13:00">13u</option>
<option value="14:00">14u</option>
<option value="15:00">15u</option>
<option value="16:00">16u</option>
<option value="17:00">17u</option>
<option value="18:00">18u</option>
<option value="19:00">19u</option>
<option value="20:00">20u</option>
<option value="21:00">21u</option>
</select></span><br>


<label for="">Tijdsduur*</label>
<span>
<select name="Tijdsduur" id="Tijdsduur" required>
<option value="2:00">2 uur varen</option>
<option value="3:00">3 uur varen</option>
<option value="4:00">4 uur varen</option>
<option value="5:00">5 uur varen</option>
<option value="6:00">6 uur varen</option>
<option value="9:00">gehele dag varen (9.00-18.00)</option>
<option value="12:00">gehele dag varen + avond (9.00-22.00)</option>
</select></span><br>


<label for="">Aantal sloepen*</label>
<span>
<select name="aantalSloepen" id="aantalSloepen" required>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select></span><br>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var date = "";
var begin = "";
var eind = "";
var aantal = "";


$('#datum').change(function() {
  date = $("#datum").val();
  console.log(date);
});
$('#beginTijd').change(function(){
    begin =( $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') ); 
    console.log(begin);      
});
$('#Tijdsduur').change(function(){
    eind =( $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') ); 
    console.log(eind);      
});
$('#aantalSloepen').change(function(){
    aantal =( $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') ); 
    console.log(aantal);

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {date:begin, quantity: aantal},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(begin , aantal);
    }
});
});

</script>
<label for="">Aantal personen per sloep*</label>
<span>
<select name="aantalPersonenPerSloep" id="aantalPersonenPerSloepSelect" 
required>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
</select><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Persoon per sloep Info" data-
toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Aantal personen (per 
sloep), NB: maximaal 540KG aan balast in totaal.">
< img src="images/info-alt.svg" alt="info">
</a>


</span><br>
<label for="">Vouchercode*</label>
<span>
<input name="VoucherCode" type="text">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Vouchercode Info" data-toggle="popover" 
data-placement="left" data-content="Heeft u een voucher of kortingscode ? 
Voer deze hier in
Heeft u een kadobon of huurtegoed vul hier dan niets in. Zodra u het email 
adres onderin invult wordt de kadobon/tegoed verrekend">
<img src="images/info-alt.svg" alt="info">
</a>
</span>
<br>
<label class="containerTest">Ik ga akkoord met de 
<a href="http://greenjoy.nl/algemene-voorwaarden/">algemene voorwaarden</a>*    
<input name="algemevoorwaardenCheckbox" type="checkbox" required>
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br><br>
<label class="containerTest">Borgsom €150.00 - verplicht*
<input name="borgCheckbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Borg Info" data-toggle="popover" data-
placement="left" data-content="De borg bedraagt 150 euro. Je ontvangt deze, 
 als er geen schade is geconstateerd, na het varen weer retour per bank.">
<img src="images/info-alt.svg" alt="info">
</a>
<br><br>
<label class="containerTest">aanmelden nieuwsbrief en aanbiedingen (2,50 
extra korting)
<input name="nieuwsbriefCheckbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br   />
<p>Verplicht veld*</p>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="form1">

</form>

<button id="submitButton" type="submit" form="form1">Volgende ></button>
<?php

$value1= $_POST['date'];  
$value2= $_POST['quantity'];     

echo $value1; 
echo $value2;



$canmakereservation = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=can_make_reservation&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556&start_time=2018-04-25 09:00&end_time=2018-04-25 12:00&quantity=5";
    $cleancanmakereservation = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", 
    $canmakereservation);
    $reservationavailable = file_get_contents("$cleancanmakereservation");
    $reservationAvailable = json_decode($reservationavailable, true);
    // echo "$cleancanmakereservation";
    // var_dump($reservationAvailable);
?>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<h3>Uw huurprijs exlusief borg: € 240,00</h3>
 <p>Dit is momenteel de laagste prijs.<br>
  - Langer varen = meer voordeel <br>
  - Vertrek voor 11.00u en na 17.00u = extra voordeel
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no. php is server-based, you need reload in order to send request to server

Comment: Be specific in your question and show us what you have tried?

Comment: @Kajbo you are wrong my friend. Ajax is the solution. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Try AJAX ... and googling in future.

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi My question is how can I check when the value of an input field changes and send that value to php without redirecting to a .php file or reloading the page

Comment: @mauro That's exactly what AJAX is for.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar, You need to use Ajax library of JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use change event for that particular input tag and use ajax for sending value to php

```
$('#emplinpt').change(function() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: {
             data: $(this).val()
         },

         success: function(data) {
             jQuery(".res").html(data);

             $('#test').html(data)
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: I used the change function but i get errors in my php. I updated my post

Comment: Undefined index: date. and the same for quantity

Comment: $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') replace and use  $(this).val()